# ActionBar style not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

Following are the styles I am applying :

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.MY_STYLE</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>  

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.MY_STYLE" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">1dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">1dip</item>
    </style>  
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
```

But both these styles are not working. Neither the width of `ActionBar` tabs are decreasing nor the background color of `ActionBar` is changing.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this?

```
  <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/wheat</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/wheat</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/wheat</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">21sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/actionbar_dr</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_dr</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_dr</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/actionbar_dr</item>
</style>
```

and remember add this style in `values-v11` and `values-v14 style.xml`

It's perfect working in my case.

[image]

Try this `drawable` as `Action Bar` Background

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
        <solid android:color="#449def" />

        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#2f6699" />

    </shape></item>
<item><shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#2f6699" android:startColor="#449def" />

        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#2f6699" />

    </shape></item>

 </selector>
```

Comment: <item name="background">#ffffff</item> gives error. And once I comment this, it sets black background. Also one of the view appears with no content.

Comment: @Nitish You just change color as per your requirement.

Comment: I have set the color as #ffffff only. Still it appears as black.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the android:background attribute (inside ActionBarStyle) doesn't tale colors but only drawable resource ( with this being said, I still can't change the color of the actionbar)